# Umbraco Admin UI not showing Tree Nodes thumbnail

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

When installing an Umbraco site, I changed my umbraco admin url from '/umbraco/' to '/myadminurl/', even before I went through the install process.

Just like it's documented, I changed in the web.config the keys 'umbracoReservedPaths' and 'umbracoPath' to match my new admin url.

Installed and everything is working fine, except for one thing:
All the nodes in the trees in all sections aren't showing any thumbnails. There used to be a win folder thumb before each tree node, but now it's just empty, except for the 'packages' node in the developer section, and for the recycle bin thumb.

Am I missing anything else I should had changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lee Kelleher answered my question in the Umbraco forum [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/13287-Umbraco-Admin-UI-not-showing-Tree-Nodes-thumbnail?p=0#comment48974).

The answer is that it looks like the image reference for the tree icons are hard-coded to use the "/umbraco" path.

2 options:

1. Manually create the path to the image? The CSS is specifically looking for...
   /umbraco/images/umbraco/sprites.png
2. Change the reference in the CSS, (rule for ".tree.tree-umbraco li a") ...
   /umbraco_client/Tree/Themes/umbraco/style.css

Cheers!

Comment: There's probably also a third option: create a [URL rewriting rule](http://borism.net/2008/11/26/url-rewriting-with-iis-and-umbraco/) to redirect `^~/umbraco/(images/.*)$` to `~/myadminurl/$1`